# Add dynamic watermark to PDF

Tags: php, linux, pdf, watermark

So I have developed a PHP tool which allows our accounts department to manipulate PDFs.
Once they are finished modifying a PDF they wish to be able to add a watermark which will be its Invoice number.
I was using a PHP library called FPDF but this fails if the PDF is version 3 for some reason.

I haven't been able to find a way of doing this either through PHP or by using a Linux command (Using PHPs shell_exec function).
Another problem is that sometimes the PDF is encrypted and needs a password to be modified which we won't know.

The basic flow would be

1. PDF is downloaded into a directory ready for accounts to process
2. Accounts process the PDF
3. An invoice number is automatically created
4. Invoice number is watermarked onto the PDF and the PDF is moved to a processed directory

All of which works until we get to the watermarking.

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine (pdf)images with Imagick, you could layer your watermark and set opacity :

```
    $combined = new \Imagick("background.jpg");

    $image = new \Imagick("watermark.jpg");
    $image->setImageOpacity(0.7);
    $combined->compositeImage($image, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 354, 237);

    $combined->setImageFormat("pdf");
    $combined->setResolution(300,300);
    $combined->setImageProperty('title', 'your file');
    $combined->setFilename("your file.pdf");

    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your file.pdf"');
    echo $combined;
    exit;
```

Or set an annotation:

```
function annotateImage($imagePath, $strokeColor, $fillColor)
{
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));

    $draw = new \ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setStrokeColor($strokeColor);
    $draw->setFillColor($fillColor);

    $draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
    $draw->setFontSize(36);

    $text = "Imagick is a native php \nextension to create and \nmodify images using the\nImageMagick API.";

    $draw->setFont("../fonts/Arial.ttf");
    $imagick->annotateimage($draw, 40, 40, 0, $text);

    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some information to the things you'd used before: FPDF cannot handle existing PDFs, so I guess you'd used [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/fpdi) in combination with FPDF to re-create the initial document.

The free version of FPDI does not support a compression feature introduced in PDF 1.5. Anyhow we offer a commercial add-on which adds support for this: The [FPDI PDF-Parser](https://www.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser).

Anyhow, neither FPDI nor the FPDI PDF-Parser support reading of encrypted/protected PDF documents.

BUT: Especially for watermarking we offer another product (not free!) that is made exactly for such purpose: The [SetaPDF-Stamper](https://www.setasign.com/stamper) component.

It also allows you to add new content to PDF documents which are also encrypted/protected. This can be done by [authenticating](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-core-manual/standard-encryption/#index-4) with the owner password or by bypassing the restriction (we can offer support for this, if we know what you are doing exactly through our support channel).

A simple watermark could be done like this:

```
require_once('library/SetaPDF/Autoload.php');
// or if you use composer require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

// create a file writer
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_File('processed/directory/result.pdf');
// load document by filename
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename('your.pdf', $writer);

// create a stamper instance for the document
$stamper = new SetaPDF_Stamper($document);

// create a font for this document
$font = new SetaPDF_Core_Font_TrueType_Subset($document, 'fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf');

// create a stamp with the created font and font size 60
$stamp = new SetaPDF_Stamper_Stamp_Text($font, 60);
// center the text to the text block
$stamp->setAlign(SetaPDF_Core_Text::ALIGN_CENTER);
// set text for the stamp
$stamp->setText($theInvoiceNo);

// add the stamp to the center of the page and rotate it by 60 degrees
$stamper->addStamp(
    $stamp,
    [
        'position' => SetaPDF_Stamper::POSITION_CENTER_MIDDLE,
        'rotation' => 60
    ]       
);

// stamp the document
$stamper->stamp();

// save the file and finish the writer (e.g. file handler will closed)
$document->save()->finish();
```